# How to fix WITH statement not valid at this position for this server version LATEST VERSION INSTALLED

Tags: mysql

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oegb8.png)MySQL Workbench tells me that can't find WITH valid for this server version although I already have the latest SERVER version installed - 5.7.27. Workbench is 8.0.17

```
WITH all_customers_and_reps AS 
(
    SELECT customer.customerNumber, customer.salesRepEmployeeNumber
    FROM customer
    WHERE salesRepEmployeeNumber = 1166
)
SELECT * FROM all_customers_and reps;
```

Comment: Upgrade. Common table expressions are not available in versions prior to 8.0

Comment: 5.7.27 is not the latest version, It's 8.0+

Comment: The only fix on MySQL 5.7.27 and lower is using `SELECT customer.customerNumber, customer.salesRepEmployeeNumber
    FROM customer
    WHERE salesRepEmployeeNumber = 1166` as a CTE (Common table expressions) can be considerd as a "temporary/intermediate table"

Comment: The server version is 5.7.26 I meant, sorry. It is the latest server version. The workbench is 8.0.17 which I already have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Common table expressions available starting from  mysql versions 8.0
You could sobstitute with a dinamic/temporary table eg:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT customer.customerNumber, customer.salesRepEmployeeNumber
    FROM customer
    WHERE salesRepEmployeeNumber = 1166

) all_customers_and reps;
```

Comment: I know, thanks. But I want to use their recursive property.

Comment: I modified the topic's title and desc. Check again please

Comment: you need  the mysql 8.0  ..  at least.. if you really need you should eval an upgrade

Comment: I already have it installed. I posted an image in the description.

Comment: you need  mysql server 8.0  (or sup)  ..  you have mysql workbench ( is the IDE)  and others  features  8.0 ....  but not mysql server ... is the mysql server the component taht parse and eecute  the sql statement  ..  https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/  .. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL

Comment: Ok I get it. The .msi installer didn't want to install a version higher than 5.7.26. I found a .zip on mysql.com. Thanks